# Don't understand my template's problem with content div's (check linked template for better understanding)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a template (link below) using HTML/CSS but I am having a major setback in finishing my template. I am using colored borders to show how I want my template to be. Everything is working pretty well except for one major drawback:

- [Template Link on CodePen](https://codepen.io/whodislol/pen/zYrGZYp)
- *.page-content* (green dashed border) and *.main-page* (purple solid border) does not contain the *.content* div's and change height when more *.content* div's are added

```
<header>
    <p class="center-align-VH">Header</p>
</header>

<div class="page-content">

    <div class="main-page">

        <div class="content-title"><a name=""></a><h1 class="center-align-VH">Title - Title - Title</h1></div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag</h2>
            <p>The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace.<br><br>Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built. The year is 1715. Pirates rule the Caribbean and have established their own lawless Republic where corruption, greediness and cruelty are commonplace. Among these outlaws is a brash young captain named Edward Kenway. His fight for glory has earned him the respect of legends like Blackbeard, but also drawn him into the ancient war between Assassins and Templars, a war that may destroy everything the pirates have built.<br><br>Welcome to the Golden Age of Piracy.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-navigation">
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Navigation 01</a></div>
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Navigation 02</a></div>
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Super ---------- Super Super Super Long Navigation Test 01</a></div>
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Super ---------- Super Super Super Long Navigation Test 02</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.page-content {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px dashed #0F0;
}

.main-page {
    width: 74%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #F0F;
}

.content-title {
    width: 70%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #000;*/
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.sidebar-navigation {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0PX 5px;
    float: right;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #F00;
}

.sidenavigation {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.center-align-VH {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

If you have any suggestions or ideas on how I can fix this problem without changing the general template, please let me know.

Comment: [A few ways to contain floats](https://pageaffairs.com/notebook/containing-floats/)

Comment: I want to recommend you looking in to flexbox too! Floats can be super frustrating so if you want to make your life easier you should definitely consider looking into flexbox or even CSS-grids!

Comment: Also you don't need all of those `position: relative;`.  you should only need to declare that position on the parent of a `position: absolute;` element.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to my answer for you.  I would not recommend turning your entire page into a table with `display: table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the height from `html, body` and `.page-content` and `.main-page` then add a `div` at the end of your `.page-content` div to clear the floats.  See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/e7bfyjkp/4/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="sidebar-navigation">
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Navigation 01</a></div>
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Navigation 02</a></div>
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Super ---------- Super Super Super Long Navigation Test 01</a></div>
        <div class="sidenavigation"><a>Super ---------- Super Super Super Long Navigation Test 02</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfloats"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px dashed #0F0;
}

.main-page {
    width: 74%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #F0F;
}
.clearfloats {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your css : 
it will make your html and body take the 100% height of the screen.

```
html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    body {
        width: 100%;
        display: table-cell;
    }

    html,
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```